# Extracting sub elements from a matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
0   0   0   138
0   8   0   0
0   1   0   0
131 0   0   138
0   0   138 0
0   0   0   0
0   115 0   8
```

and this index vector:

```
idx = [2,4,5]
```

I need to get the row-index and the col-index from the matrix for all the entries with 138, but, for only the rows in idx.

Comment: How is your matrix stored?

Answer (score 0):

If you store the matrix like this:

`matrix = [ [0, 0, 0, 138], [0, 8, 0, 0], ... ]`

Then your work is pretty easy:

```
result = []
for i in idx:
    row = matrix[i]
    for j in range(len(row)):
        if row[j] == 138:
            result.append((i, j))
return result
```

Comment: I did it the same way, but I wanted something like the below.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `numpy`, you should try to do this in a vectorised fashion:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 138],
              [0, 8, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0],
              [131, 0, 0, 138],
              [0, 0, 138, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 115, 0, 8]])

idx = np.array([2, 4, 5])

match = np.argwhere(A == 138)
res = match[np.in1d(match[:, 0], idx)]

# array([[4, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the row indices directly on `A` and then search for `138`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 138],
...               [0, 8, 0, 0],
...               [0, 1, 0, 0],
...               [131, 0, 0, 138],
...               [0, 0, 138, 0],
...               [0, 0, 0, 0],
...               [0, 115, 0, 8]])
>>> 
>>> idx = np.array([2, 4, 5])
>>> 
>>> y, x = np.where(A[idx]==138)
>>> y = idx[y]
>>> y, x
(array([4]), array([2]))
```